# SQL query to generate the following output

Tags: sql

Display user id, user name, total amount, amount to be paid after discount and give alias name as User_ID, user_name, Total_amount, Paid_amount. Display record in descending order by user id. Click on [TABLE SHCEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Epu.jpg) to get the table

This is the code I've written. But this is not showing the expected result:

```
SELECT 
    USERS.USER_ID AS User_ID,
    NAME AS user_name,
    (FARE * NO_SEATS) AS Total_amount 
FROM 
    USERS 
INNER JOIN 
    TICKETS ON USERS.USER_ID = TICKETS.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    PAYMENTS ON TICKETS.TICKET_ID = PAYMENTS.TICKET_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    DISCOUNTS ON PAYMENTS.DISCOUNT_ID = DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_ID 
GROUP BY 
    USERS.USER_ID, NAME, FARE, NO_SEATS
ORDER BY 
    USERS.USER_ID DESC;
```

This is the expected output:

```
USER_ID USER_NAME   TOTAL_AMOUNT   PAID_AMOUNT
----------------------------------------------
 5       Krena           700         625
 4       Johan           800         775
 3       Ivan           3000        2900
 1       John           4000        3950
 1       John           4000        3950
 1       John           2000        1900
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, try it

```
SELECT 
USERS.USER_ID AS USER_ID,
USERS.NAME AS USER_NAME,
(TICKETS.FARE * TICKETS.NO_SEATS) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
(TICKETS.FARE * TICKETS.NO_SEATS - DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT) AS PAID_AMOUNT 
FROM 
USERS 
INNER JOIN TICKETS 
        ON USERS.USER_ID=TICKETS.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN PAYMENTS
        ON TICKETS.TICKET_ID=PAYMENTS.TICKET_ID 
INNER JOIN DISCOUNTS
        ON PAYMENTS.DISCOUNT_ID=DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_ID 
ORDER BY USERS.USER_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
SELECT 
USERS.USER_ID AS USER_ID,
USERS.NAME AS USER_NAME,
(TICKETS.FARE * TICKETS.NO_SEATS) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
(TICKETS.FARE * DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT) + TICKETS.FARE AS PAID_AMOUNT 
FROM 
USERS USERS
INNER JOIN TICKETS TICKETS
        ON USERS.USER_ID=TICKETS.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN PAYMENTS PAYMENTS
        ON TICKETS.TICKET_ID=PAYMENTS.TICKET_ID 
INNER JOIN DISCOUNTS DISCOUNTS
        ON PAYMENTS.DISCOUNT_ID=DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_ID 
ORDER BY USERS.USER_ID DESC;
```

I'm confused in your database structure if why is it in number datatype? you might want to change it to decimal if you want and make its length as (11,2) because i assume that your discount amount in your DISCOUNT table is in percentage right? Or just paste your sample database here so i can update my code.

Comment: DISCOUNT is in amount not in percentage and i am getting exact output for first three column except the last one.What would be the exact code for discount column? @G.Panga

Comment: JUST change "(TICKETS.FARE * DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT) + TICKETS.FARE AS PAID_AMOUNT" to "(DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT - TICKETS.FARE) AS PAID_AMOUNT" if you will just subtract the DISCOUNT from your FARE

Answer (score 0):

if i had enough reputation, i would have written this as a comment (sigh):
u havent quite defined what ur expected results are.

i assume the following:

- print the total sums for a user, both the Total_amount (ie. official price), Paid_amount (ie. after discounts), so it would include all the tickets and their payments.
- i assume that the discount is a positive number to be deducted from the fair and is per 1 seat

then this should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT 
  USER_ID AS USER_ID,
  NAME AS USER_NAME,
  sum(FARE * NO_SEATS) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
  sum((FARE - DISCOUNT_AMOUNT ) * NO_SEATS) AS PAID_AMOUNT 
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN TICKETS t
        ON u.USER_ID=t.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN PAYMENTS p
        ON t.TICKET_ID=p.TICKET_ID 
INNER JOIN DISCOUNTS d
        ON p.DISCOUNT_ID=d.DISCOUNT_ID 
group by USER_ID, name
ORDER BY USER_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer for the question and would give the accurate output

```
 SELECT User_ID, (select name from users u where t.user_id=u.user_id) as 
user_name, ticket_id as Ticket_id, (no_seats*fare) as Total_amount, 
((no_seats*fare)-(select discount_amount from discounts d 

where d.discount_id=(select discount_id from payments p where t.Ticket_id=p.Ticket_id))) as Paid_amount 

FROM tickets t ORDER BY User_ID desc;
```

Answer (score -2):

Write a query to

> display user id, user name, ticket id , total amount, amount to be
>   paid after discount and give alias name as User_ID, user_name,
>   Ticket_Id, Total_amount, Paid_amount. Display record in descending
>   order by user id.

Avoid duplicate records.

[Note : Total amount to be paid should be number of tickets * amount per ticket ]

this code runs 100%

[image]